# How do I Cmd+D in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I recently started using WebStorm, and I can't seem to find this feature there at all. It's the one where you pick multiple matching bits of text one by one in a file and edit them all together.

<kbd>Cmd + D</kbd> just duplicates the selected text.

Comment: Do you mean [Multiple cursors and selection ranges](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/multicursor.html)?

Comment: yes, TYSM!! it was ^G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to select the next occurrence in JetBrains IDEs, you can use `Alt + J` (or `Ctrl + G` on MacOS).

To unselect it, add `Shift`.

If you want to select *all* occurrences, press `Ctrl + Shift + Alt + J` (or `Ctrl + Cmd + G` on MacOS).